# Does an unused let binding have any effect in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I just realised that it is actually legal to write this:

```
let _ = sum [1..100]
in  "Hello"
```

The let-binding appears to do *absolutely nothing*.

But now I'm wondering about the *exact* semantics here. It is possible to write a program which contains a `_` binding, and yet deleting that binding would visibly alter the meaning of said program?

Basically, I'm wondering whether it's safe to automatically delete such bindings. As far as I can tell, the *value* of this binding cannot possibly affect anything. However, it seems hypothetically possible that it's *type* might affect something else. Can anybody construct an example?

Comment: `let in "Hello"` is valid too.

Comment: Holy cow... I was sure that would be disallowed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is one example.  With the `_` binding, the output is `8.0`, but without it, it is `8`.  (Admittedly, this isn't a very big difference, but I'm sure this could be used as a basis for something more substantial.)

```
main :: IO ()
main = let x = 5
           _ = asTypeOf x 6.0
       in print $ x + 3
```

Comment: Nice find. Here, the defaulting mechanism makes `x` to be Integer "unless there is a reason to do otherwise". From a practical point of view this may be convenient. From the theoretical point of view this looks as a "special case" making the semantics more complex than needed.

Comment: Disabling the monomorphism restriction did not change this behaviour. I thought that would have been enough to make `x` polymorphic, essentially making the `asTypeOf x 6.0` a compile-time no-op, but I was wrong. Adding `x :: Num a => a` _does_ make it a no-op, instead, which puzzled me.

Comment: @chi That's because local binds are monomorphized unless explicitly made polymorphic. Adding a type signature for `x` makes it polymorphic explicitly, such that it's defaulted independently of the other binding in the `print` line.

Comment: @Carl Ah! I did not realize local binds are handled differently with respect to monomorphism. I guess that the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` applies only to the top level bindings, then.

Comment: @chi Yep. There's another extension, `NoMonoLocalBinds` that (usually) makes local binds polymorphic by default. However, it's not compatible with some other extensions, so sometimes it doesn't turn on even if you specify it.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by explaining why this happens. Though it is definitely a good find!

Answer (score 10):

I think in this example `x` has type `Num a => [a]`, but without the second line it would be `(Num a, Monad m) => m a`. Don't have GHCi on this computer to double check, though.

```
let x = return 3
    _ = sum x
 in x
```

Comment: `x` has type `Num a => [a]` because `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`.

Comment: Good point. I forgot that the 3 could be any num and not just an integer one. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

A pathological example, but I think it qualifies your requirement

> It is possible to write a program which contains a _ binding, and yet deleting that binding would visibly alter the meaning of said program?

which the compiler rejects unless you remove that line:

```
main = 
  let _ = void main() { fprintf STDERR "I'm a confused C programmer" }
  in print "I'm not"
```

Comment: But does it qualify as a Haskell program though? xD